# Rewriting Query for Fetching Database Value

Tags: database

I am trying to rewrite below query to fetch on database value off Models 
But am failing on in the new code, can any one help in to rewrite in query based on joomla latest standards

**Old Code**

```
<?php 
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
if(isset($_GET["s"])){  
$ModelId=$_GET["s"];
$sql = "SELECT * from #_toy_products where prod_status='1' and prod_cat_id='".$ModelId."' order by prod_sorder Asc";
$db->setQuery($sql);
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();
$list='<select name="model" class="list-box" id="model"  lang="" title="Model">';
$list.='<option value="" style="padding-left:10px;" selected>-Select Model-</option>';
foreach($rows as $row){
    $list.='<option value="'.$row->prod_id .'" style="padding-left:10px;">'.$row->prod_name.'</option>';
}
$list.='</select>';
die($list);
```

}
?>

New Code

```
<?php 
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select($db->quoteName(array('Model', 'state', 'prod_cat_id', 'prod_sorder')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__toy_products'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('state=1') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote('\'custom.%\''));
$query->order('prod_sorder ASC');
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
// GET using JInput
$jinput  = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$ModelId = $jinput->get('s', '', 'INT');

// Database stuff
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select($db->qn(array('Model', 'state', 'prod_cat_id', 'prod_sorder')))
      ->from($db->qn('#__toy_products'))
      ->where($db->qn('prod_status') . ' = 1')
      ->where($db->qn('prod_cat_id') . ' = ' . (int)$ModelId)
      ->order('prod_sorder ASC');
$db->setQuery($query);

$rows = $db->loadObjectList();

$list = '<select name="model" class="list-box" id="model"  lang="" title="Model">';
$list .= '<option value="" style="padding-left:10px;" selected>-Select Model-</option>';

foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $list .= '<option value="' . $row->prod_id . '" style="padding-left:10px;">' . $row->prod_name . '</option>';
}

$list .= '</select>';

die($list);
```

---

As you can see at the beginning, I've used `JInput` instead of `$_GET`.

`$ModelId = $jinput->get('s', '', 'INT');` ...the `->get()` function takes 3 arguments:

- Variable name (in your case `s`)
- Default value (left if as default but you can use one if you like)
- Filter (set to `INT`(integer) assuming this variable will be a number)

---

There were also some tweaks needed to your `->where()` clause in the query.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, awesome - only thing is die($list); in end is necessary as the model is not popping up if this line is not added

Comment: @Ruchika - That's an odd way of populating a modal but if that's the way you're happy with, fair enough. Added it to the code in my answer as a reference.

Comment: Thanks - is there any security risk in adding that - die($list); - because withoout it the modal is not popping up
Appreciate your time and expertise in replying

Comment: I wouldn't say security risks. I don't know exactly where you're adding this code but I personally wouldn't use `die()` when rendering a modal.